# Solving $\frac{L_m}{L_{tot}}=\frac{\sin(\theta/n_s)}{\sin(\theta/2)}$ for $\theta$

Tags: trigonometry

The problem I am trying to solve for $\theta$ is:
$$
\frac{L_m}{L_{tot}} = \frac{\sin (\theta/n_s)}{\sin(\theta/2)}
$$
The Result that Maple provides me is in line 2.
I am uncertain how to interprete the result and am wondering how to derive the solution myself.
Can someone let me know if this is possible and how to?
[Problem and Maple solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GmbQ.png)

The application is that I would like to define an arc based on the chord length $L_tot$ and the number of members $n_s$ in a Rainbow bridge that each have the member length $L_m$. Thus the only unknown in the equation is theta.

I appreciate any suggestions

I added one more image of my handwritten derivation of the formula including sketches that explain the geometric meaning of the parameters.[formula derivation and geometry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfcxd.jpg)

Comment: Shouldn't that be $\sin(\theta/(2n_s))$ on the top?  After all, if $n_s = 1$, then there's only one member, which should have the same length as the chord ($L_m = L_{tot}$.)

Comment: Hi there I appreciate your effort and apologize for not being clear enough. This is my first post and I am not really sure yet how to make my problem most clear.
n_s is not the number of members n_m but the number of segments  and n_s=n_m+1.
A rainbow bridge has at least 2 members, so three segments, the case for n_s < 3 does not make sense geometrically.

Answer (score 1):

I don't expect that this equation can be solved by algebraic methods, for the following reasons:

Assuming that the equation is supposed to involve $\sin(\theta/2 n_s)$ in the numerator:  define $y = L_{tot}/L_m$ and $\alpha = \theta/2 n_s$.  Then we have
$$
\frac{\sin n_s \alpha}{\sin \alpha} = y. 
$$
There is a trigonometric identity which states that
$$
\frac{\sin n_s \alpha}{\sin \alpha} = (2 \cos \alpha)^{n_s - 1} - {n_s - 2 \choose 1} (2 \cos \alpha)^{n_s - 3} + {n_s - 3 \choose 2} (2 \cos \alpha)^{n_s - 5} - \cdots 
$$
where the series terminates so that it only contains positive powers of $\cos \alpha$.
So defining $x \equiv 2 \cos \alpha$, this reduces to finding the roots of the polynomial
$$
x^{n_s - 1} - {n - 2 \choose 1} x^{n_s - 3} + {n - 3 \choose 2} x^{n_s - 5} - \cdots = y.
$$
Unfortunately, this is as far as algebra can take you in general.  For $n_s \geq 6$, this is a fifth-order polynomial, and it is not possible to find the roots of a general polynomial of order 5 or greater using algebraic techniques.  Even for $n_s = 4$ or $n_s = 5$, you'd have a cubic or quartic polynomial in $x$, and those are generally not worth the trouble to solve algebraically.

You can always resort to numerical solutions, though.  For example, for $n_s = 7$ you would have
$$
x^6 - 5 x^4 + 6 x^2 - 1 = y.
$$
You could then plot the polynomial on the left-hand side and figure out for what value of $x \in [0,2]$ it takes the value of $y$;  you would then have $\theta = 2 n_s \arccos(x/2)$.  [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com) will also find the numerical solutions for you to a high degree of accuracy.

Of course, if you're going to have to resort to numerical technique, such plotting and reading from graphs, you might as well do it with the original function rather than this algebraically transformed one.